# Edge Animate Define Starting Point Other Than the Beginning on Page Load

Tags: jquery-animate, adobe-edge

How do I start a timeline as a specific point in time when a new page loads?

I am making a thumbnail image timeline in Edge Animate for a portfolio page. The basic interactivity is fine, it goes back and forth and I can choose what ever image I want. however I am having trouble figuring out how to start the timeline in a specific location based on the image displayed, such as the last image, or somewhere in the middle.

My issue is that when image 21 is shown, the timeline below is showing the first seven images, not the last seven, because the timeline always starts from the beginning.

For instance, the timeline has 21 thumbnail images, seven shown at once. For the first seven this is not an issue since the timeline starts at the beginning. However if I want the thumbnails to start from image 8, which initially is out of frame, I can't seem to code it to start at that position when the next 7 images are shown.

I tried putting a "Play from" at the spot where I want the second group of pictures to show but nothing other than it starts at the beginning so I'm obviously doing this incorrectly.

I am not sure how to code it to have the timeline start from a specific position other than the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the answer. The stage onLoad command will accomplish this if you put a "stopAt" in the code. When the page loads it will go to the point in the timeline when that page loads.